# How can I display a submit button at the side of each output text

Tags: html, jquery

I want to display one button at the side of each output text.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    $("p").html($("p").html() + " " + getVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery input value</legend>
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  </fieldset>
  <button id="btn">display value</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    let getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    let button = `<button name="button-${getVal}">Button for ${getVal}</button>`
    $("#output").html($("#output").html() + " " + getVal + button);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery input value</legend>
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  </fieldset>
  <button id="btn">display value</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Also, you can add an attribute for each button to identify them modifying this line:

```
let button = `<button name="button-${getVal}">Button for ${getVal}</button>`
```

(Example with name attribute).

Comment: can you tell me i want to display a check box also if you could please ....

Comment: @Aisha So use let checkbox = `<input type="checkbox" id="name="button-${getVal}"" name="button-${getVal}" value="Bike">`; and add it in the same way as that button

Comment: hey @Symphonic can you tell me how can i bring an edit button on click output value and can be edit please help me if you could...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
            $("p").html(''+getVal+' <input type="button" value="MyButton"/>');
        });
    });
```